# F# dynamic lookup operator (?) overloading

Tags: dynamic, f#, operator-overloading

Can't define (?) operator overload on type:

```
type Foo =
     val s : string
     new(s) = { s = s }
     static member (?) (foo : Foo, name : string) = foo.s + name

let foo = Foo("hello, ")
let hw  = foo? world

// error FS0043: The member or object constructor 'op_Dynamic'
// takes 2 argument(s) but is here given 1. The required signature
// is 'static member Foo.( ? ) : foo:Foo * name:string -> string'.
```

All works fine if I use standalone let-binding for operator definition:

```
let (?) (foo : Foo) (name : string) = foo.s + name

let hw  = foo? world
```

But I need to specify `op_Dynamic` operator directly for type `Foo`. What's wrong with the first code snippet?

Using `F# 1.9.7.4` @ Visual Studio 2010 Beta2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps there is an easier way (I'll look), but this will do in a pinch:

```
type Foo =     
    val s : string     
    new(s) = { s = s }     
    static member (?)(foo : Foo, name : string) = 
        foo.s + name

let inline (?) (o:^T) (prop:string) : ^U =
    (^T : (static member (?) : ^T * string -> ^U)(o,prop))

let foo = Foo("hello, ")
let hw  = foo ? world 
printfn "%s" hw
```

Comment: Easier way?!? Yes, it works, but why I should put this "inline (?)" workaround into any class with overloaded (?) operator just to use it? Why I can't use defined operator overload directly?

Comment: Yes, it turns out there is a bug in the F# parser and your original code should work.  Thanks for pointing this out!  I've filed the bug.